# Converter caracteres especiais para \uxxxx em Python

Tags: python, json, unicode

Eu estou usando uma API que não está aceitando caracteres especiais enviados diretamente no payload JSON (como á, ó, ã...) e preciso converter esses caracteres para \uxxx. Por exemplo "não" -> "n\u00e3o". No Python, ele converte \uxxxx automaticamente para um caractere unicode, mas eu gostaria de fazer a operação inversa e converter, por exemplo, a palavra "não" para "n\u00e3o".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se tratando de json especificamente, basta usar o método nativo, `json.dumps()`, ele já faz o *unicode-escape* automaticamente, ficando:

```py
import json

payload = json.dumps({
    "chave1": "letra á, letra é, letra í, letra ó, letra ú",
    "chave2": "letra do alfabeto cirílico: ф",
    "array1": ["avião", "a letra ó", "letra do alfabeto cirílico: ф"]
})

print(payload)
```

Saída:

```js
{"chave1": "letra \u00e1, letra \u00e9, letra \u00ed, letra \u00f3, letra \u00fa", "chave2": "letra do alfabeto cir\u00edlico: \u0444", "array1": ["avi\u00e3o", "a letra \u00f3", "letra do alfabeto cir\u00edlico: \u0444"]}
```

Funcionará com string também:

```py
import json

y = json.dumps("a letra ó Ó, a letra do alfabeto cirílico: ф")

print(y)
```

Saída:

```js
"a letra \u00f3 \u00d3, a letra do alfabeto cir\u00edlico: \u0444"
```

> **Nota:** que a string retornada irá possuir aspas nas extremidades e aspas (double-quotes) também serão *escapados*

Teste online no ideone: https://ideone.com/NJBTWH

### Usando `unicode-escape` e `backslashreplace`

É possível usar o `unicode-escape`, o problema é que ele irá transformar quebras de linha em `\n` e se esse não for o seu objetivo, pode complicar, mas é possível configurar como deseja tratar a saída com [`str.encode`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode).

Como pode ver pelo link da documentação, por padrão `str.encode(encoding='utf-8', errors='strict')` usa `encoding='utf-8'` e `errors='strict'`, no seu caso você quer que qualquer caractere especial esja "escapado" e caracteres comuns (provavelmente ASCII) sejam mantidos, então deverá usar `enconding='ascii'`, isso fará o `str.encode()` codificar tudo o que é possível em ASCII, o que não for possível irá causar erro, para isso você deverá tratar os erros com `errors='backslashreplace'`, ele usar a forma hexadecimal do *Unicode code point* com formatos `\xhh` `\uxxxx` `\Uxxxxxxxx`.

```py
print('Olá mundo! ß, ♬'.encode('ascii', errors='backslashreplace'))
```

Saída:

```
b'Ol\\xe1 mundo! \\xdf, \\u266c'
```

E para tornar em str novamente use o [`bytes.decode()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode):

```py
print('Olá mundo! ß, ♬'.encode('ascii', errors='backslashreplace').decode())
```

Aqui pode conferir a diferença dos resultados:

```py
x = '''Olá mundo!
letras: Á á É é Õ õ
outros: ф ß ♬
Emojis:  ‍‍‍'''

unicode_escape = x.encode('unicode-escape').decode()

customizado = x.encode('ascii', errors='backslashreplace').decode()

print("unicode_escape:")
print(unicode_escape)

print("\ncustomizado:")
print(customizado)
```

Saída:

```
unicode_escape:
Ol\xe1 mundo!\nletras: \xc1 \xe1 \xc9 \xe9 \xd5 \xf5\noutros: \u0444 \xdf \u266c\nEmojis: \U0001f600 \U0001f468\u200d\U0001f469\u200d\U0001f467\u200d\U0001f466

customizado:
Ol\xe1 mundo!
letras: \xc1 \xe1 \xc9 \xe9 \xd5 \xf5
outros: \u0444 \xdf \u266c
Emojis: \U0001f600 \U0001f468\u200d\U0001f469\u200d\U0001f467\u200d\U0001f466
```

### Referencias

- Sobre o parâmetro `enconding=`, leia mais na documentação: https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings
- Sobre o parametro `errors=`, leia mais na documentação: https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#error-handlers